# Excel VBA - Adjusting a formula to let VBA loop it

Tags: vba, excel

I have following formula

> =IF(Matching_Sheet!F3=0;"";Matching_Sheet!F3)

I want to let VBA fill in the B column of a sheet with this formula adjusted to the respective column number. I have tried this

```
For x = 2 To destMaxRow
Range("$B$" & x).FormulaLocal = "=IF(Matching_Sheet!$F$=0;" & x & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";Matching_Sheet!$F$)" & x
Next
```

Unfortunately, this form apparently has a mistake but I cannot figure out what it is.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, try this

```
For x = 2 To destMaxRow
  Range("$B$" & x).FormulaLocal = "=IF(Matching_Sheet!$F$" & x & "=0;" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";Matching_Sheet!$F$" & x & ")"
Next
```

Which I think could be shortened to (obviating need for a loop)

```
Range("$B$2:B" & destMaxRow).FormulaLocal = "=IF(Matching_Sheet!$F2=0;" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";Matching_Sheet!$F2)"
```